# Most efficient approach to finding common opponents pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with match results, I'm trying to calculate stats between players based on common opponents. I'm struggling to think of an efficient approach. What I'm currently doing is generating a dictionary with the players as keys and as values a set of players they have played against. The next step is generating another dictionary with as key the pair of players and as values the opponents they have had in common and then I iterate over the DF, filter the DF on matches that were played in the past and on only matches that were played between one of the players and one of the common opponents. This works but it is not very fast. I'm aware that it will never be very fast but I feel like there is a better approach. Here is a sample:

```
Winner Loser Date    Other stats
A      B     1-1-13  XX
A      C     1-2-14  XX
B      A     2-2-14  XX
C      D     1-3-14  XX
C      A     2-3-14  XX
D      A     3-3-14  XX
```

So the common opponents set would be:

```
A,B: {}
A,C: {D}
A,D: {C}
B,C: {A}
B,D: {A}
C,D: {A}
```

Stats could be things like average win%

Comment: what is your expect output? which stats do you want to calculate?

Comment: Added some information, thanks